# Variable undefined in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting undefined variable error in Laravel for the code section: (this is index.blade.php file)

```
 @foreach($faqs as $faq) 

  <tr>
  <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
  <td>{{$faq->question}}</td>
  <td>{{$faq->descripton}}</td>
  </tr>
```

though I send the variable in this file via Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $faqs = Faq::all();
    return view('admin.faq.index')->with('faqs', $faqs);
}
```

The Faq Model is :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Faq extends Model
{
    //
}
```

the error message I am getting is
[image]

How can I solve this? TIA.

Comment: `return view('admin.faq.index')->with(['faqs'=> $faqs]);` try this `->with() ` accept array

Comment: `return view('admin.faq.index')->with('faqs', $faqs);` is incorrect, it should be an array with key/value as `return view('admin.faq.index')->with('[faqs' => $faqs]);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the data in an `array`(`->with()` method) or you can use  `compact` method too.

```php
return view('admin.faq.index', compact('faqs'));
```

Or

```php
return view('admin.faq.index')->with(array('faqs'=>$faqs));
```

Comment: still getting same error. this is the file https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/resources/views/admin/faq/index.blade.php

Comment: Did you even read the answer before saying you still get an error? Because that's how you solve the error.

Comment: @NabidAnzum you need to change it in your controller file you need to pass your `faqs` data in array if you are using `with()`. `->with('[faqs' => $faqs]);`

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `compact` method as below:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{

    $faqs = Faq::all();
    return view('admin.faq.index',compact('faqs'));
}
```

Comment: still getting same error. https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/resources/views/admin/faq/index.blade.php this is the file.

Comment: do you have data in FAQ table?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like $faqs is empty. You can check that with @isset().
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements

Comment: he is not asking to handel error and `empty` and `isset` both are diffrent